# Best practice for same result - Python

Tags: python

I'm currently learning python with googles education for it and have a quick question regarding the best practice out of the two answers; Googles answer and the way I have done it.

Guidelines of exercise:

```
# D. MixUp
# Given strings a and b, return a single string with a and b separated
# by a space '<a> <b>', except swap the first 2 chars of each string.
# e.g.
#   'mix', pod' -> 'pox mid'
#   'dog', 'dinner' -> 'dig donner'
# Assume a and b are length 2 or more.
```

Googles Code:

```
def mix_up(a, b):
  # +++your code here+++
  # LAB(begin solution)
  a_swapped = b[:2] + a[2:]
  b_swapped = a[:2] + b[2:]
  return a_swapped + ' ' + b_swapped
  # LAB(replace solution)
  # return
  # LAB(end solution)
```

My code:

```
def mix_up(a, b):
  return '%s %s' % (b[0:2] + a[2:], a[0:2] + b[2:])
```

Which one is a better practice to use and what is the reason behind it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [ask] and [help/on-topic]

Comment: `[0:2]` is the same as `[:2]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question might be more suitable for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

As Burhan Khalid mentioned `a[0:2]` is the same as `a[:2]` (which seems more readable to me).

Today python programmers use

```
"{} {}".format(b[:2] + a[2:], a[:2] + b[2:])
```

See for example: https://pyformat.info/

This version and your version might be better. See https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/304445/why-is-s-better-than-for-concatenation

In terms of beginner level reding the Google code perhaps wins.

Comment: In py3.6, you can use `f"{somevar}"` instead of `"{}".format(somevar)`, which is the best thing ever.

Comment: Thanks Kyticka,

Looking at format it seems much more efficient as well since you can define place holders via {1} which i have used before in c#.

I've omitted the 0's as well.

I understand the google version is much easier for a beginner to read however I was more wondering if theirs a benefits to declaring variables and using them to return a result other then a single line of code handling everything. 

Thank you for the links though, very helpful!

Comment: I am glad we could help and welcome to the SO! Just a quick remark the community here prefers upvoting or marking as an answer instead of using thanks comments (not your case as you mentioned C#).

Comment: @kyticka Long time lurker first time poster haha. I'll take that on board :)